# Why does my twitter boostrap page go off edges of the page?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am very new to Twitter bootstrap and am having problems with the following structure

```
<Container> - Using Fluid container
   <Row 1>      
     <Column 1> - Covers 6 columns
       <Row 1> - Electricity
       <Row 2> - Electricity Graph
       <Row 3> - Electricity Table
    </Column 1>
    <Column 2> - Covers 6 columns
      <Row 1> - Gas
      <Row 2> - Gas Graph
      <Row 3> - Gas Table
    </Column 2>
  </Row 1>
  <Row 2> - covers entire width
     Table
  </Row 2>
<Container>
```

[See here for page](http://dashboards.stcenergy.com/DashboardProblem)

As you can see the content has gone off the edge of the page on the left

Does anyone know what could cause this?

How can I get a reliable small margin left and right?

Chrome even has issues rendering the first header

Somehow the content is wider than the actual browser width which has caused the horizontal scroll bar, although there is not a big overlap?

The markup is too big to post here so [here](https://www.stcenergy-online.com/dev/index.txt) is a link to it.

Comment: We know how bootstrap works! That doesn't need to show us, but the relevant markup and css would be helpful to help you. And looking deep into the link is no-one's subject to care....

Comment: I think it's your SVG. Take a look at your DOM inspector. You'll see that's the element that sticks out.

Comment: I have added a link to show the markup.  I was not trying to show anyone how boot strapper works, just how I am trying to use it

Comment: What do you mean jeremy?  Are you talking about the charts?  Not sure what I am supposed to do to fix this?  I need the charts where they are

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to two different things going on. First off like Paul mentions in the comments above the SVG charts are too large for the containers and is pushing out the boxes. This can be fixed by adding an `overflow:hidden` to the `<div class="col-md-6">`

Secondly the way you are using the bootstrap `.row` class is incorrect and its messing up the layout. For example your structure is using this:

```
<!-- THIS IS NOT CORRECT NESTING -->
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="heading row">...</div>
    <div class="row">...</div>
    <div class="row sectionHeading">...</div>
    <div class="row">...</div>
</div>
```

The `.row` should only be used to contain the columns `.col-xs-*, .col-sm-*, .col-md-*, .col-lg-*` as the direct child of `.row`. If they are nested incorrectly then margin and padding problems occur because the `.row` has negative left and right margins to adjust the gutters in the columns. In the example above the `.row` class should be removed because the divs will stack on top of each other naturally and they are creating the unnecessary space.

With that said the one thing I found odd was that in order to remove the horizontal spacing altogether is I had to remove all instances of the `row` tag when they should have worked as in tended... hope that helps.

Comment: upvoted it after I added a little bit more about nesting

Comment: Thanks @Christina I was leaving work and didn't have time to re-read through what I wrote to make edits.

Comment: Thanks!  I made these tweaks and it works a lot better now!  It is strange how the row class causes problems but never mind, its working without it for now :)